# Optional Field Update Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small form connected to an optional field in my database. it is not required in any way.

if you visit the page on there is nothing in the input field it gives me a $gamername undefined. also when visiting the page it automatically shows the echo statement of "GameName Updated" when i haven't even click the form button. if i put something in the form it will up date it to the db as it should.. but it also wont echo the field unless i refresh the page but then it submits it all over again.

```
<?php

   if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {    
    $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '{$user_id}' ";    
    $result = query($sql);

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

        $user_id = $row['uid'];
        $gamename = $row['gamename']; 

    }
}

?>
<?php

function update_game_name(){

        $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];           
        $gamename = escape($_POST['gamename']);        

        $sql ="UPDATE users SET gamename='$gamename' WHERE uid='$user_id'"; 
        $result = query($sql);

            echo ('GameName Updated.');



        }
 ?>
<div class="container no-scope-wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <?php update_game_name(); ?>
     <div class="no-scope-border">    
         <h2 class="form-field-title">Game Name</h2>
             <form role="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-field-label">GameName</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="name" name="gamename" type="text" placeholder="GameName" value="<?php echo $gamename;?>">
                </div>              
                <button type="submit" name="update_game_name" id="btn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Update GameName</button>              
             </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you need to check if there is post data after making the update:

```
  function update_game_name(){

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]!="POST") return;

    $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];           
    $gamename = escape($_POST['gamename']);        

    $sql ="UPDATE users SET gamename='$gamename' WHERE uid='$user_id'"; 
    $result = query($sql);

    echo ('GameName Updated.');



  }
```

Note that this function is called every time you load the page. The warning message is shown because the function was called without post data.

Comment: Flgor it still wont echo out the value in the field unless i revisit the page.

Comment: Check if the $sql is executed making `echo $sql` in some parte after creating the variable. Also check if session is opened before using $_SESSION

Comment: Flgor ok i added this header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); it works but when update it wont display gamename updated echo

Answer (score 1):

As @FIgor already said, your function runs every time you load the page and does not check for posted data. And also you do not fill the variable "$gamename" with the new data after posting. There are 2 options to achieve what you want.

1. Use the function as you already have, but only if the form is submitted and before retrieving the users data from the database, to be sure you read in your variable the new, updated data from the databse:

   if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
       $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['gamename']) && $_POST['gamename'] != '')
        update_game_name();

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '{$user_id}' ";    
   $result = query($sql);

   while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

       $user_id = $row['uid'];
       $gamename = $row['gamename']; 

   }
   ```

   }
   ?>`

And you do not call your function anymore in your html part.

or

2. Check inside your function for posted data, as FIgor advised, but make it return the new, updated value.

   function update_game_name(){

   ```
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]!="POST") return;

   $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];           
   $gamename = escape($_POST['gamename']);        

   $sql ="UPDATE users SET gamename='$gamename' WHERE uid='$user_id'"; 
   $result = query($sql);

   echo ('GameName Updated.');

   return $gamename;
   ```

   }

And then call the function like this:

```
$gamename = update_game_name();
```

Comment: moni_dragu it all works but it echos gamername updated 2 time one outside the div one inside

Comment: which approach did you use?

Comment: I used as you suggested if you look at my html i use this  <?php update_game_name(); ?> to call

Comment: I suggested 2 options: 
- in the first approach you use your function at the top of the script and do not use it in your html anymore.
- in the second approach you only use it in your html (div)
So, either way, you only call the function once.

Comment: i under stand what you are saying my issue is when i use option 2 it wont update the field to display current